# PyCharm CE reports `out of memory` even though set and restarted

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

My PyCharm CE reported `not enough memory` and requires me to increase `Xmx` setting. I increased and saved but it seems not valid and the IDE keeps reporting the same error.

The parameters showing in the popped error window:

```
-Xmx: 4000MB (current value: 750)  
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize Unknown MB (current value unknown)  
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize: 2400MB (current value: 240)
```

And I also checked `$HOME/.PyCharmCE2018.3/config/pycharm64.vmoptions` as suggested. The parameters indeed changed as I modified. I'm confused since I have set a much larger value than `current value` but no effects. What should I do?

More info:

```
PyCharm 2018.3 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-183.4284.139, built on November 21, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b15 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.15.0-39-generic
```

Comment: Are you executing 64 bit version?

Comment: I have added the env info.

Comment: It's better to report issue on YouTrack attaching logs folder zipped (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files): http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY.

Comment: @y.bedrov Thank you and the problem is not showing today. I will try your suggestion once it happenes again.